# Replace new line breaks only between two tags in php

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I have content managed in TinyMCE.  I have a class called code and I need to replace line breaks in PHP but only between two tags.

So my html will look something like this

```html
<p>hello see my css below</p>
<p class="code">

h1 { 
font-size:10px
font-color:#FFF
}

h2 { 
font-size:10px
font-color:#FFF
}

</p>
```

In CSS, I have a `<code></code>` tag that will put line numbers by each line automatically.  I therefore want to replace the above to something like this:

```html
<p>hello see my css below</p>
<p class="code">
<code>h1 {</code> 
<code>font-size:10px</code> 
<code>font-color:#FFF</code>
<code>}</code>
<code></code>
<code>h2 { </code>
<code>font-size:10px</code>
<code>font-color:#FFF</code>
<code>}</code>
<code></code>
</p>
```

I take it I want to str_replace or preg_replace every line break with `</code>`
`<code>`.  However, I can't work out how to do it only between `<p class="code">` and `</p>`

As always, help is appreciated.

Comment: Not had any responses.  Just come back onto this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I threw together a quick and dirty solution to your problem. It doesn't cover additional attributes in your `.code` paragraph (you would most likely need to change the first `explode` to `preg_split` and use some regex to get that to work).

It may not be the *best* way to solve your problem, but it seemed to work for your stated requirements.

```
function codify($string){
    $final = '';
    $array = explode('<p class="code">',$string);
    if(count($array)){
        foreach($array as $k=>$str){
            if($k == 0){
                $final .= $str;
            }
            else{
                $tmp = explode("</p>",$str);
                $tmp2 = explode("\n",$tmp[0]);
                $final .= "<p class=\"code\">\n<code>".implode("</code>\n<code>",$tmp2)."</code>\n</p>".implode("</p>",array_slice($tmp,1));
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $final = $string;
    }
    return $final;
}
```